# How to upgrade alfresco 5.0 to 6.0

Tags: ubuntu, alfresco

I have a server with alfresco 5.0 installed in /opt/alfresco-5.0/
In it the most important folders are alf_data, postgresql, tomcat, java and libreoffice, so it's running on those services and in those folder are binary files for those programs that alfresco service run when I start alfresco.

The documentation for upgrading is really confusing and I have no idea where to begin. I'm running on ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's bellow applies to Alfresco enterprise version and some things may need to be tweaked to align with community.

In terms of steps you cannot upgrade from 5.0 to 6.0 straight away you'll need to go through the path bellow (unless you already have 5.0.5 installed):

- 5.0 -> latest 5.0 service pack (5.0.5)
- 5.0.5 -> 6.0

There is no in-place upgrade mecanism, so you'll need for each step to deploy an alfresco instance and copy over configuration/customizations, DB & contentstores from the old to the new instance, and then reindex content. I would recommand you of course do backups and test at each step the application is running as expected.

Your description of your current alfresco installation in /opt/ makes me think it was originally installed using the binary installer which shipped all the components (a jre, postgresql db server, and so on...).
This installer doesn't exist anymore in version 6.x and you will have to install every component yourself (e.g. using you package manager - if it provides appropriate components versions - or manually) and adapt configuration accordingly.
Make sure to install each component as per the compatibility matrix: https://docs.alfresco.com/6.0/concepts/supported-platforms-ACS.html (or the one for your target version of Alfresco)

Another important difference is that in 6.0 Alfresco does not embed the Solr FTS server. It is now a separate module (Alfresco Search service) you'll need to installation and reindex your whole repository.

May sound overwheming but if you don't have customizations that should not be a big deal.

Comment: Is alfresco just an amalgamation of these services: java, tomcat, postresql, libreoffice are you saying I should upgrade the binary for each one. For instance alfresco 6.0 tomcat is Tomcat 8.5.34. So should I run "apt install Tomcat 8.5.34" and then replace all the files inside /opt/alfresco/tomcat with the installed version? Something like that?

Comment: well there are a bunch of other things to take care of but yes, Alfresco is just a webapp tomcat (on some other web application servers) runs. Actually that's several webapps (alfresco, share & solr)
So yes you can install tomcat (as long as the versio match) using your package manager, a binary distribution or possibly compiling it manually.... Same goes for the DB. Alfresco though expects to find some system tool like libreoffice, imagemaigck and so on... So you'll have to make sure config match the path where you install stuff